# web cam is not identified by jmf

Tags: java, opencv, jmf

i used jmf jar file to run my web cam. here my code.It doesnt show my web cam when run this code? can anyone give me a solution ? Thanks

```
CaptureDeviceInfo di = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice("vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0";);
ml = di.getLocator();
```

Answer (score 0):

My JMF application also can't find any device.
I solved this problem by using following code:

```
MediaLocator ml = new MediaLocator("vfw://0");
```

where `vfw://0` is the path to web camera, you can find it at JMStudio.